# ROBOT framework: using environment variables in argument file

Tags: robotframework

Here's a basic rundown of what I want to do:

I want to call my scripts using an argument file. But the argument file needs to work on an environment variable for the path.  So, for example, the argument file may be:

**args.robot**

```
[ROBOT_HOME variable]/test1.robot
[ROBOT_HOME variable]/test2.robot
[ROBOT_HOME variable]/test3.robot
```

And I would define the `ROBOT_HOME` variable at the environment level:

```
$ export ROBOT_HOME=/path/to/tests/
$ pybot -A args.robot
```

None of the following substitutions for `[ROBOT_HOME variable]` in the **args.robot** file have worked:

- `$ROBOT_HOME`
- `${ROBOT_HOME}`
- `%{ROBOT_HOME}`

And neither of the following pybot commands have worked:

- `pybot -A args.robot`
- `pybot -v ROBOT_HOME:$ROBOT_HOME -A args.robot`

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-file-syntax) is of help, please see.

Comment: @Rao Yea I looked there and didn't see anything about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

@Rao gives a good solution for the problem. The last part of the [documentation on arguments file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-file-syntax) demonstrate how to programmatically generate argumentfile and use them with a one-liner.

```
generate_arguments.sh | robot --argumentfile STDIN
generate_arguments.sh | robot --name Example --argumentfile STDIN tests.robot
```

The quesion remaining now is what can the `generate_arguments.sh` be? Il like to use [envsub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html), envsub replace environnement variables in a script (for linux env)

```
envsubst '$HOME' < "argumentfile.txt" > "argumentfile.txt"
echo "argumentfile.txt"
```

Another possibility to run that script would be:

```
generate_arguments.sh && robot --argumentfile "argumentfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

@xNok Solution would work, but it is not very accurate. You can not rewrite a file with `envsubst` command. Take a look into this thread.

[rewriting a file with "envsubst file" leaves it empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081507/why-does-rewriting-a-file-with-envsubst-file-file-leave-it-empty)

So, basically if you want to get it working in this way, the argument file would look like this:

```
export HOME='your/path'
envsubst '${HOME}' < argumentfile.txt > argumentfile_tmp.txt && mv argumentfile_tmp.txt argumentfile.txt
```

And for instance the "argumentfile.txt" would look like this:

```
--variable PATH:${HOME}/some/sub/path
```

Then as suggested by @xNok, you can run the script this way:

```
generate_arguments.sh && robot --argumentfile "argumentfile.txt"
```

Please note that this method would overwrite the "argumentfile.txt". So, every time you need to clone the source code or the other option is to use `envsubst` to write to a temporary file.