# Why does rewriting a file with "envsubst <file >file" leave it empty?

Tags: bash, unix, environment-variables

I need to put some environment variables values to file.

```
cat file
# $VAR

echo $VAR
# text
```

When I do `envsubst '$VAR $VAR' < file > file` file becomes empty. To resolve this issue I use `envsubst '$VAR $VAR' < file | tee file 2>&1 >/dev/null`. But sometimes it doesn't work, I mean file becomes empty. The first question is why sometimes file becomes empty and the second is what is the TRUE Unix way to put env vars to file in Linux and *BSD and MacOS ?

Comment: Use: `envsubst < file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Comment: `cmd file > file` is 99.9999% always the wrong approach in `*nix` (unix&Linux). Get used to using @anubhava 's pattern for any simple file changes you need to do in `*nix`. Good luck.

Comment: another note: `bash` doesn't look into single quotes.

Comment: Not *remotely* specific to `envsubst`. You can have this problem with *literally any* command when you're both reading from and writing to the same file via redirection.

Comment: Thanks everybody for help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The shell *always* processes the output redirection, which truncates the file, before starting the command.

With the pipeline `envsubst ... < file | tee file`, the two commands `envsubst` and `tee` run *asynchronously*, which means the OS is free to start one or the other command first. You are basically tossing the dice that `envsubst` runs and reads `file` before `tee` runs and truncates the file.

The only correct solution is to write to a temporary file, then replace the original with the temporary file *after* you have confirmed that the command was successful.